# Python calculate surface area bounded by the parallels lat1 and lat2 and the meridians lon1 and lon2

Tags: python, matlab, math, geometry, area

I'm looking for an equivalent to this Matlab function [`areaquad`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/areaquad.html) in Python.

> area = areaquad(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) returns the surface area bounded
> by the parallels lat1 and lat2 and the meridians lon1 and lon2. The
> output area is a fraction of the unit sphere's area of 4π, so the
> result ranges from 0 to 1.

Do you happen to know how I can calculate this using Python?
Any tips are much appreciated!

Comment: Did you Google for this at all before asking?  The first Google hit is https://sites.utexas.edu/utarima/files/2020/04/areaquad.pdf .

Comment: Yes, and I've already tried it out as is, but it yields None.

The input parameters in my use case are 
 values = (-90,-180,-89,180) # lat, lon, lat, lon
which also seem quite different from those in the pdf.

Comment: (-90, 180, -89, 180) does not describe a rectangle, it describes a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard to calculate it, if you need it only for spheres. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment) is the formula for calculating total area of sphere surface between two latitudes. So:

```
h = sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)
Az = 2 * pi * h
```

Now, we can simply find the proportion of the region restricted between two longitudes:

```
Aq = Az * (lon2-lon1)/(2*pi)
```

And finally, to make the result a fraction of surface of unit sphere, divide it by `4*pi`.
Putting all together, with simplification and take angle units into account:

```
 A = (sind(lat2)-sind(lat1)) * deg2rad(lon2-lon1) / (4*pi);
```

Hope you can translate it to python.

[image]

**Edit:**
This is what I get in R2020b for your test case:

```
lat1 = -90; lat2 = -89; lon1 = -180; lon2 = 180;
A = (sind(lat2)-sind(lat1)) * deg2rad(lon2-lon1) / (4*pi)
```

> A =
> 7.6152e-05

[image]

Also, about `Aq` not being present in the final formula:

```
h = sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)
Az = 2 * pi * h
Aq = Az * (lon2-lon1)/(2*pi)
   = 2*pi*h*(lon2-lon1)/(2*pi) // reducing 2*pi
   = h * (lon2-lon1)
   = (sin(lat2)-sin(lat1))*(lon2-lon1)
A  = Aq/(4*pi)
   = (sin(lat2)-sin(lat1))*(lon2-lon1)/(4*pi)
```

Comment: Hey @saastn,

that looks promising, thanks a lot! 
I'm getting a different result with your function though.
The **Matlab** function yields **9.5674e-** and **Python** yields **7.6152e-05**.
I'm also wondering why **Aq** is unused in **A**.

Comment: I edited my post, @thomaschhh. If you get 7.6152e-05 in python, that's correct. I'm not sure why MATLAB yields different result on your system. It's 7.6152e-05 here.

Comment: I double-checked the function in Matlab and I just saw that the name of the function there is _area_quad_.  The source code to that function can be found here: <https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/quad_mesh/quad_mesh.html>
Anyway, I think I will go with your version. Again, thanks for your help!